# star motion NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have Schwarzschild Lagrangian:

```
    L = (1/2)*((1 + (-((2*G*M)/(r[\[Tau]]*c^2))))*c^2*
    Derivative[1][t][\[Tau]]^2 - 
    1/(1 - (-((2*G*M)/(r[\[Tau]]*c^2))))*Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]]^2 - 
    r[\[Tau]]^2*(Derivative[1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]]^2 + 
    Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]]^2 Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]]^2))
```

and these are Euler-Lagrange equations:

```
    EQ\[Theta]2 =D[L, \[Theta][\[Tau]]] - D[D[L, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]], \[Tau]] == 0 
    EQ\[Phi]2 =D[L, \[Phi][\[Tau]]] - D[D[L, \[Phi]'[\[Tau]]], \[Tau]] == 0
    EQr2 = D[L, r[\[Tau]]] - D[D[L, r'[\[Tau]]], \[Tau]] == 0
    Derivative[1][t][\[Tau]] = (En r[\[Tau]])/(-2 G M + c^2 r[\[Tau]])
```

These are the physics constants:

```
    En = 0.99; M = 4.3 10^6; c = 63197.7909261(*AU/year*); G = 
    4 \[Pi]^2(* AU^3Msun^-1year^-2*);
    Derivative[1][t][\[Tau]]
```

I tried to solve the equations:

```
    ss = NDSolve[{EQ\[Phi]2, EQr2, EQ\[Theta]2, 
    r[0] == 1758.4646597315134, 
    r'[0] == 0.13814885940063001, \[Phi][0] == 
    0, \[Phi]'[0] == -0.1*r'[0], \[Theta][0] == \[Pi]/2, \[Theta]'[
    0] == 0.1 \[Phi]'[0]}, {\[Phi], r, \[Theta]}, {\[Tau], 1992.224, 
    2010}, Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, 
    Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

The initial conditions r[0] and r'[0] were given by positions of S2 star at 1992.224. But if I solve the equations i get a straight line and not an ellipse.

```
     \[Phi]\[Phi][tt_] := \[Phi][tt] /. ss[[1]] /. tt -> \[Tau]
     rr[tt_] := r[tt] /. ss[[1]] /. tt -> \[Tau]
     \[Theta]\[Theta][tt_] := \[Theta][tt] /. ss[[1]] /. tt -> \[Tau]
     x[tt_] :=rr[tt] Sin[ \[Theta]\[Theta][tt]] Cos[ \[Phi]\[Phi][tt]] /.ss[[1]] /. tt -> \[Tau]
     y[tt_] :=rr[tt] Sin[ \[Theta]\[Theta][tt]] Sin[ \[Phi]\[Phi][tt]] /.ss[[1]] /. tt -> \[Tau]
     z[tt_] := rr[tt] Cos[ \[Theta]\[Theta][tt]] /. ss[[1]] /. tt -> \[Tau]
     ParametricPlot[{x[\[Tau]], y[\[Tau]]}, {\[Tau], 1992.224, 2010}]
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few typos and missinterpretation how to define functions.

Correct t to r in L

```
L = (1/2)*((1 + (-((2*G*M)/(r[\[Tau]]*c^2))))*c^2*
 Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]]^2 - 
1/(1 - (-((2*G*M)/(r[\[Tau]]*c^2))))*Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]]^2 - 
r[\[Tau]]^2*(Derivative[1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]]^2 + 
   Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]]^2 Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]]^2)
 )
```

In Euler equations correct also t to r and use Equal (==) in the last line.

```
EQ\[Theta]2 = 
D[L, \[Theta][\[Tau]]] - D[D[L, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]], \[Tau]] == 0
EQ\[Phi]2 = 
D[L, \[Phi][\[Tau]]] - D[D[L, \[Phi]'[\[Tau]]], \[Tau]] == 0
EQr2 = D[L, r[\[Tau]]] - D[D[L, r'[\[Tau]]], \[Tau]] == 0
Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]] == (En r[\[Tau]])/(-2 G M + c^2 r[\[Tau]])

En = 0.99; M = 4.3 10^6; c =   63197.7909261(*AU/year*); G = 
4 \[Pi]^2(*AU^3Msun^-1year^-2*);
```

You don't need all the options in NDSolve, the initial definitions are defined at tau=1992.22 not 0. NDSolve does not know `\[Phi]'[0] == -0.1*r'[0]` , insert the known number for r'[0] and the same for phi'[0].

```
ss = NDSolve[{EQ\[Phi]2, EQr2, EQ\[Theta]2, 
  r[1992.224] == 1758.4646597315134, 
  r'[1992.224] == 0.13814885940063001, \[Phi][1992.224] == 
  0, \[Phi]'[1992.224] == -0.1*0.13814885940063001, \[Theta][
 1992.224] == \[Pi]/2, \[Theta]'[1992.224] == 
 0.1 - 0.1*0.13814885940063001}, {\[Phi], r, \[Theta]}, {\[Tau], 
 1992.224, 2010}]
```

ss was ordered to  give pure functions for r, phi, theta. So following function definition is better.

```
\[Phi]\[Phi][tt_] = \[Phi][tt] /. ss[[1]]
rr[tt_] = r[tt] /. ss[[1]]
\[Theta]\[Theta][tt_] = \[Theta][tt] /. ss[[1]]
x[tt_] = rr[tt] Sin[\[Theta]\[Theta][tt]] Cos[\[Phi]\[Phi][tt]]
y[tt_] = rr[tt] Sin[\[Theta]\[Theta][tt]] Sin[\[Phi]\[Phi][tt]]
z[tt_] = rr[tt] Cos[\[Theta]\[Theta][tt]]

ParametricPlot[{x[\[Tau]], y[\[Tau]]}, {\[Tau], 1992.224, 2010}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry why should I correct t to e in L?

Comment: What function should t have? Is it an additional variable? Then you should solve for in NDSolve.

Comment: I didn't say, correct t to e, but t to r !!!  Please read correctly.

Comment: yes sorry I mean r, I just wrote the Schwarzschild Lagrangian and this is the known form

Comment: As i wrote in my answer, i think that `Derivative[1][t][\[Tau]]^2 ` in your L is a typo. What else than r should t mean here?

Comment: I mean t'[tau]...the derivative of t with respect to tau.

Comment: Anyways I should expect an ellipse, I don't know how to do this because the initial conditions on r and r' are fixed!

Comment: The result is part of an ellipse. Do `ParametricPlot[{{x[\[Tau]], y[\[Tau]]}, {-x[\[Tau]], 
   y[\[Tau]]}, {x[\[Tau]], -y[\[Tau]]}, {-x[\[Tau]], -y[\[Tau]]}}, {\
\[Tau], 1992.224, 2010}] ` .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but in the Lagrangian the right form is with t'[tau] in the first term.